# Return all records from parent table if id = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, union

Let's say I have a table that assigns `Users` as managers for division(s) such as:

`UserManagerTable`:

```
ID      UserId    DivisionId
1       23        1
2       45        0
```

When `DivisionId = 0` it is meant to represent that the user is assigned as a manager to **All Divisions** in the `Divisions` table.

I would like to know the best possible way to query this table to return `DivisionId's` and if `DivisionId = 0` then return all `DivisionIds` from the `Divisions` table.

```
SELECT DivisionId FROM UserManagerTable...?

DivisionId
1
1
2
3
...
...
30
```

Initially I thought I could do something like:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN DivisionId  = 0 THEN (Select DivisionId FROM Division)
    ELSE DivisionId 
END AS DivisionID
FROM PoAppApprovedRequestor
```

But that did not get me what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select d.*
from divisions d
where exists (select 1
              from usermanager um
              where um.id = @id and
                    (um.divisionid = 0 or um.divisionid = d.divisionid)
             );
```

Comment: I was about to tell him to use subquery. 

Answer (score 0):

you can use query like below

```
;with newUserManagerTable as 
(
select ID,UserId,D.DivisionId from
from UserManagerTable U Join Divisions D
  on U.DivisionId=D.DivisionId or U.DivisionId=0
)

--you query here on newUserManagerTable
```